# Autodesk Forge - Extract geometry data from a 2D Cad Drawing using the modelderivative API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-model-derivative

I am trying to extract data from a 2d Cad drawing. Essentially I would like to find the x/y coordinates of every element. However, the data does not show this information.

I am using the `modelderivative/v2/designdata/{{urn}}/metadata/{{guid}}/properties` endpoint to extract the data itself.

Here is an example of the output this gives

```
{
            "objectid": 3308,
            "name": "Text [67AC]",
            "externalId": "67AC",
            "properties": {
                "AnnotationScaling": {
                    "Annotative": "No"
                },
                "General": {
                    "Color": "ByLayer",
                    "Handle": "67ac",
                    "Layer": "IMAGE-HYPERLINKS",
                    "Linetype": "ByLayer",
                    "Linetype scale": "1.000",
                    "Lineweight": "ByLayer",
                    "Name ": "Text",
                    "Plot style": "ByColor",
                    "Thickness": "0.000",
                    "Transparency": "ByLayer"
                },
                "Hyperlinks": {
                    "Description": ".\\R0010020.JPG",
                    "Name": ".\\R0010020.JPG"
                },
                "Misc": {
                    "Backward": "No",
                    "Upside down": "No"
                },
                "Text": {
                    "Contents": "R0010020.JPG",
                    "Height": "0.050",
                    "Justify": "Left",
                    "Obliquing": "0.000 deg",
                    "Rotation": "111.348 deg",
                    "Style": "Standard",
                    "Width factor": "1.000"
                }
            }
        },
```

As you can see, there is no key 'Geometry'

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how I can extract the object positioning data for a 2d Cad drawing? Could it be that the drawing itself needs to implicitly set this information?

Here is an example of what I'm seeing in the Cad drawing itself.

[Cad Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEaok.png)

There is no mention of the correct keys "Position X", "Position Y" in the modelderivative output above. Can anyone explain why this might be? Am I exporting it incorrectly? Or does Forge remove this information?

I am using PHP and getting the data server-side.

I exported another test model and found the following was generated

```
"Geometry": {
   "Area": "1131855.821",
   "Circumference": "3771.382 mm",
   "Diameter": "1200.468 mm",
   "Radius": "600.234 mm"
}
```

But there are no X/Y/Z coordinates in this data.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the individual primitives of your 2D drawing on the client side based on this blog post: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/working-2d-and-3d-scenes-and-geometry-forge-viewer.

Parsing the drawing geometry on the server-side would be a bit more involved, since the file format used in Forge Viewer is not publicly documented. You could use tools like https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge.commandline-nodejs, but I'm not sure if there are alternatives for PHP.